# Why does my Powershell runbook not understand the time properly?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

I have Azure instances with two tags, PHExempt which is TRUE or FALSE, and a tag called OpeningHours which contains a string like 0900->1730-M->F for when it is meant to be on and working.

The following function turns the machines off when it's time to be off, but doesn't turn them on when they're meant to be on ONLY when it's run from an Azure powershell runbook. It runs fine from a laptop (the usual "it works on my machine" eh). Why?

```
  foreach ($box in ($environment | Sort-Object -Property Name)) {
# I don't know why but for some reason $box.Name in a string doesn't swap in, we need to set a display name in the loop
$displayName = $box.Name

$boxOpening = Get-Date -Hour ($box.Tags.OpeningHours.Split("->")[0]).substring(0,2) -Minute ($box.Tags.OpeningHours.Split("->")[0]).substring(2,2)
$boxClosing = (Get-Date -Hour ($box.Tags.OpeningHours.Split("->")[2]).substring(0,2) -Minute ($box.Tags.OpeningHours.Split("->")[2]).substring(2,2))

if ($boxClosing.Hour -lt 12) { #do we close in the morning?
  $boxClosing = $boxClosing.AddDays(1) #tomorrow not today
}

if (($currenttime -gt $boxOpening) -and ($currenttime -lt $boxClosing)) {
  $shouldBeOn = "TRUE"
} else {
  $shouldBeOn = "FALSE"

}


$Name = $box.Name
Write-Host "$Name opens at $boxOpening and closes at $boxClosing, should be on is $shouldBeOn"

if ($shouldBeOn -eq "FALSE") {
  if ($box.Tags.PHExempt -eq "FALSE") {
    if ((Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $box.ResourceGroupName -Name $Name -Status | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Statuses `
           | Where-Object { $_.Code -match "PowerState" } | `
           Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayStatus) -eq "VM running") {
      Stop-AzureRmVM -Name $box.Name -ResourceGroupName $box.ResourceGroupName -Force
    }
  }
} elseif ($shouldBeOn -eq "TRUE") {
  if ((Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $box.ResourceGroupName -Name $Name -Status | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Statuses `
         | Where-Object { $_.Code -match "PowerState" } | `
         Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayStatus) -eq "VM deallocated") {

    Start-AzureRmVM -Name $box.Name -ResourceGroupName $box.ResourceGroupName
  }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't work with azure, so this is a shot in the dark. Is it possible that the runbook uses a different timezone from you?

Comment: It does, but I account for that by adding a GMT offset to the code that populates $currentTime, I'd also expect that if it was a problem with that, it wouldn't turn off at the right time either? The runbook turns servers off the first time after 5:30pm that it runs, but never turns them on the first time it runs after 9:00am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time zones suck.

The problem is indeed a GMT one (Shadowzee if you add an answer instead of your comment I'll vote it the correct answer). Basically calculating the turn on time and turn off time by using get-date and overwriting the hours with the times in the tag doesn't work if GMT is currently yesterday compared to AEST. The logs showed - on closer inspection, the lack of the machines being turned on because the current time is not between the opening and closing times YESTERDAY.